# Will token based pagination will give better performance than offset based pagination in a Graph database?

Tags: database, graph, pagination, gremlin

Will `Token based` pagination give better perforance than `offset based` pagination in Graph database?

Currently, I am using gremlin `range()` for the pagination & looking for other options.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using `range` can work but each time the query is run with a different range the query is likely going to be re-run and then the different range applied. The effectiveness of using `range` will really depend on how much work it takes each time for the query to run. Getting all of the results one time into an in-memory cache of some type and then fetching from there as needed can be a more performant way to paginate.